# Get a date range in 24 hour format in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to know is this query part is correct or not:

```sql
DATE_FORMAT(@co, '%Y-%m-%d %T') between '2014-03-24 13:00:00' and '2014-03-25 00:00:00'
```

because I'm getting wrong output from this query. Can anyone can tell what is wrong with it ?

Here `@co` is a string value which I want to convert as a 24hr date format.

Answer (score 0):

Whether results are correct depend on what `@co` contains. But, as its name suggests, [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) expects a **date**, not a string.

You should note that MySQL can handle dates as any other data type—you don't need to convert them to strings.